# What is the meaning of \meaning?

Tags: tex-core

In the code of `endnotes.sty` there is a command `\meaning` that is used in the following definition

```
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
     \if@enotesopen \else \@openenotes \fi
     \begingroup
        \def\next{#1}%
        \newlinechar='40
        \immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
     \endgroup}
```

If I remove it, it doesn't work anymore (I get the funny error `Undefined control sequence. \GenericError`). What is the use of `\meaning` ?

Comment: `\meaning\meaning` is the meaning of `\meaning`.

Comment: The [endnote package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/endnotes/endnotes.sty) says "The stuff with \next and \meaning is a trick from the TeXbook, 382, there intended for setting verbatim text, but here used to avoid macro expansion when the footnote text is written."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
~ $ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*\def\test#1{This is a test #1 macro}

*\show\test
> \test=macro:
#1->This is a test #1 macro.
<*> \show\test
```

`\show` gives the meaning (definition) of a macro (or a primitive) in the log file and the terminal.
`\meaning` shows the same but puts it in the document instead. In the example above it is written to the notes file.

Answer (score 10):

If you process the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

x\endnote{Recall that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational}

\end{document}
```

you'll get a file with extension `.ent` containing

```
\@doanenote {1}
macro:->Recall
that
$\sqrt
{2}$
is
irrational
\@endanenote
```

This is a consequence of the definition

```
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
     \if@enotesopen \else \@openenotes \fi
     \immediate\write\@enotes{\@doanenote{\@theenmark}}%
     \begingroup
        \def\next{#1}%
        \newlinechar='40
        \immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
     \endgroup
     \immediate\write\@enotes{\@endanenote}}
```

and of

```
\let\@doanenote=0
\let\@endanenote=0
```

which make the two control sequences into unexpandable tokens.

The `\meaning` primitive takes as argument a single token and expands to a string representation of the token: all characters will have category code 12, except for space tokens that are normalized to character code 32 (space) with category code 10. If the token is a macro (that is, it has been defined with `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef` or `\xdef`), the representation will be of the form

```
macro:〈parameter text〉->〈replacement text〉
```

Thus, in the `endnotes` case above, `\meaning\next` will expand to

```
macro:->Recall that $\sqrt {2}$ is irrational
```

because the parameter text is empty. By rule, each control word in the string representation will be followed by a space.

The macro `\@endnotetext` does three `\write` operations. In the first, `\@doanote {1}` is written out, because `\@doanote` is not expandable so it is written out as is (with a trailing space), whereas `\@theenmark` will be expanded. Also `{` and `}` are unexpandable, so we get the first line in the example.

Then the expansion of `\meaning\next` is written, under the setting `\newlinechar='40` which means that spaces (character code decimal 32, octal *'40*) will be transformed into newline characters. I guess this is done for avoiding overlong lines, in case of long endnotes.

Finally `\@endanenote` is written (on a new line).

When the `.ent` file is read in by the `\theendnotes` command, `\@doanenote` is given a new meaning; basically it reads until `>` is found, emits `\begingroup`, sets the mark to the tokens in braces and starts typesetting the note text; `\@endanenote` is redefined to issue `\par\endgroup`.

---

What does `\meaning` return in other cases? Here are a few examples; I use plain TeX, but it would be the same in all flavors of TeX.

```
\let\foo=0 % like in endnote.sty
\def\next{Recall that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational}
\def\macro#1{Something with #1}

\tt % typewriter type

\meaning\relax

\meaning a

\meaning 0

\meaning\alpha

\meaning\foo

\meaning\next

\meaning\macro

\meaning ~

\meaning\&

\meaning\pageno % plain tex

\bye
```

[image]

A control sequence `\let` to a character will display the same as if the character was used. A control sequence defined with `\chardef` (like `\&`) gives `\char"` followed by the hexadecimal number of the character; similarly for `\mathchardef` (like `\alpha`).

The macros `\next` and `\macro` show the difference when there is a parameter text; finally, primitives represent themselves (like `\relax`). There are a few other cases, I showed `\pageno` that's defined with `\countdef`.

Comment: Thanks for these details. Is there a macro that would output `\next` in the same way as `\meaning` without the `macro:->` string ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom In LaTeX you do `\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\next`