# Why \meaningbody\box throws Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }?

Tags: macros, errors, tex-core

On the question [How to make \meaningbody say the command is undefined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389968/how-to-make-meaningbody-say-the-command-is-undefined) the `\meaningbody` command from [Equivalent of \show to display the LaTeX code in the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20365/equivalent-of-show-to-display-the-latex-code-in-the-document) was fixed to correctly display undefined commands. But after [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) commented on the [@David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) answer saying: What about `\meaningbody\box`? Then I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\meaningbody}[1]
{%
    {\ttfamily
    \ifdefined#1
        \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1
    \else
        `The command \string#1 is undefined.'
    \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\meaningbody\box

\meaning\box

\end{document}
```

And it does the strange error:

```
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.17 \meaningbody\box
```

When I just do `\meaning\box` it outputs `“box` on the PDF:

[image]

Why would be `\box` is different?

Comment: I'd extended the answer at the previous question to handle this case before seeing this question:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot work because the definition of `\strip@prefix` is actually

```
\def\strip@prefix#1>{}
```

That means, that it strips everything before the `>`.  That works perfect in case of a macro like `\mbox`.  If we look at `\meaning\mbox` we find

```
\long macro:#1->\leavevmode \hbox {#1}
```

So if we snip that at the `>` as we can do with `\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\mbox` we get the rest: `\leavevmode \hbox {#1}`.

Now `\box` is a primitive and therefore `\meaning\box` is just

```
\box
```

So where should `\strip@prefix` snip now?  It just keeps absorbing tokens, looking for `>`, until in your case something invalid is encountered and then it throws an error.