# Endnotes at the same line

Tags: endnotes

I'm struggling to make every endnote entry not take a new line. I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338315/211273) answer, which explained a lot, but didn't answer my doubt, as said, how can I make endnotes entries not start a new line.
For example:

1- entry 1 2- entry 2

Instead of

1- entry 1

2- entry 2

Comment: Do you want ALL the endntes to be one paragraph?  Or just some of them?  The former would involve a nearly complete rewire of the endnotes package.  OTOH, you can pack a savebox until you are ready to put it into an endnote.

Comment: I just want the endnotes entries not start in a new line, but start right after the last one when there is room for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In endnotes.sty, `\theendnotes` is defined as follows:

```
\def\theendnotes{\immediate\closeout\@enotes \global\@enotesopenfalse
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \edef\@tempa{`\string >}%
    \ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12%
      \let\@ResetGT\relax
    \else
      \edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
      \@makeother\>%
    \fi
    \def\@doanenote##1##2>{\def\@theenmark{##1}\par\begingroup
        \@ResetGT
        \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}%
        \enoteformat}
    \def\@endanenote{\par\endgroup}%
    \enoteheading
    \enotesize
    \input{\jobname.ent}%
  \endgroup}
```

All you need to do is to hack this to remove the `\par`s inside the definition. Here is the MWE, where two `\par`s are just removed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\makeatletter
\def\theendnotes{\immediate\closeout\@enotes \global\@enotesopenfalse
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \edef\@tempa{`\string >}%
    \ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12%
      \let\@ResetGT\relax
    \else
      \edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
      \@makeother\>%
    \fi
    \def\@doanenote##1##2>{\def\@theenmark{##1}\begingroup
        \@ResetGT
        \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}%
        \enoteformat}
    \def\@endanenote{\hspace{1em}\endgroup}%
    \enoteheading
    \enotesize
    \input{\jobname.ent}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
One\endnote{this is the first endnote. this is the first endnote.} two\endnote{this is the second endnote. this is the second endnote.} three \endnote{this is the third endnote.} 

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

You can change the space between endnotes by modifying the amount of `\hspace{1em}`.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enotez` together with `enumitem`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{itemize*}{list}{list-type = itemize*}
\setlist[itemize]{itemjoin={\qquad}}

\begin{document}

A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}
A\endnote{entry one}
B\endnote{entry two}

\printendnotes[itemize*]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good take, but I can't keep the entries together. It's a large list of contents plus questions. But I appreciate though.

Comment: @FábioJosédeJesus Sorry, but I can't understand: you asked for endnotes to be set as a single unit. Please, be more precise about your aim.